# Excel VBA Userform, Update and delete database,

Tags: excel, userform, vba

I'm very new to Excel VBA and I have found solutions to most my problem through Stackoverflow.com But still, there is a problem I've couldn't solve.
I am working on a multidimensional Userform to maintain our database. The Userform I'm working on containing option boxes, checkboxes, textboxes and combo boxes.
After long search and work, I fixed the search bottoms and they all are working. But I can not get the Update bottom and the Delete bottom to work.
I have uploaded the file, I would be grateful if anyone can help me out with this issue.

```
Private Sub bt2_Click() 'Update shipment
Dim sonsat As Long, sor As String
If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "Choose an item", vbExclamation, ""
Exit Sub
End If

sor = MsgBox("Are your sure?", vbYesNo, "")
If sor = vbNo Then Exit Sub

lastrow = Sheets("logbook").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, 
LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
sonsat = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(sonsat, 1) = op1
Cells(sonsat, 2) = op2
Cells(sonsat, 3) = chb1
Cells(sonsat, 4) = chb2
Cells(sonsat, 5) = tb14
Cells(sonsat, 6) = tb1
Cells(sonsat, 7) = tb2
Cells(sonsat, 8) = tb3
Cells(sonsat, 9) = tb4
Cells(sonsat, 10) = tb5
Cells(sonsat, 11) = cb1
Cells(sonsat, 12) = tb6
Cells(sonsat, 13) = tb7
Cells(sonsat, 14) = tb8
Cells(sonsat, 15) = tb9
Cells(sonsat, 16) = cb2
Cells(sonsat, 17) = tb10
Cells(sonsat, 18) = tb11
Cells(sonsat, 19) = tb12
Cells(sonsat, 20) = cb3
Cells(sonsat, 21) = cb4
Cells(sonsat, 22) = tb13


MsgBox "Item Has Been Changed", vbInformation, ""
ListBox1.list = Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:V" & 
Sheets("logbook").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

If Me.op1.Value = True Then
Cells(sonsat, 1).Value = "X"
Else
Cells(sonsat, 1).Value = "-"
End If

If Me.op2.Value = True Then
Cells(sonsat, 2).Value = "X"
Else
Cells(sonsat, 2).Value = "-"
End If

If Me.chb1.Value = True Then
Cells(sonsat, 3).Value = "X"
Else
Cells(sonsat, 3).Value = "-"
End If

If Me.chb2.Value = True Then
Cells(sonsat, 4) = "X"
Else
Cells(sonsat, 4) = "-"
End If
End Sub



Private Sub bt3_Click() 'delete shipmet
Dim sil As Long
Dim e, b, c, d As Integer


If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "Choose an entry", vbExclamation, ""
Exit Sub
End If

If ListBox1.ListIndex >= 0 Then
cevap = MsgBox("Entry will be deleted. ... Are you sure ?", vbYesNo, "")
If cevap = vbYes Then
Sheets("logbook").Range("A:A").Find(What:=ListBox1.Value).Activate
sil = ActiveCell.Row
Sheets("logbook").Rows(sil).Delete
End If
End If

For d = 1 To 2
Controls("op" & d) = False
Next

For c = 1 To 4
Controls("cb" & c) = "-"
Next

For b = 1 To 2
Controls("chb" & b) = False
Next

For e = 1 To 14
Controls("tb" & e) = ""
Next

ListBox1.list = Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:V" & 
Sheets("logbook").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This is pretty hard to test without the userform or sample data (it looks like the latter would only need to be minimal). Are you getting an error message? If so please share it. Or is it running through but just not doing what you want? I guess those questions apply to both `Sub`s. Personally, I'd add `Option Explicit` at the top of the code which will force you to declare your variables but may also automatically highlight other issues.

Comment: In the meantime, here are some thoughts. When you update your row, you aren't using e.g. `cb1.value` just `cb1`. I'd try the former, though I don't think it can be the cause. When you update the cells you aren't specifying the worksheet. It might not be a problem, but it's something I'd check.

Comment: Similarly, when updating the controls, in the delete sub, I think you should have `.value`.

Comment: Steve, Thank you for your comments. I tried once the Option Explicit, but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, do you have an error message?

Comment: the code is run-time 91 "object variable or with block variable not set".
is there any way that I can attach the file?

Comment: I don't think SO provides anything, but you could post a link to a Dropbox shared file or similar. On that error message, can you tell what part of the code triggers it? Hint: add debug.print statements to the code at strategic points to see where it gets to and to output the value of key variables.

Comment: the Debug is in update bottom and it highlights the ( "Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate")

Comment: I have shared the file in google drive and here is the link 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2w6D_6K2zGneURKVkhvaFBNbWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It's time for bed here, but first: in that part of the code the version you posted is split over two lines without a continuation character. You can't end a line with `&` probably that's not how you have it really, but best to check the 'easy' possibilities first!

Comment: Oh wait, that's the similar line from the delete code. By the way, I think you mean 'button' not 'bottom'.

Comment: Before that line of code could you add a `Debug.Print Listbox1.Value`? The idea is to check that that definitely holds smithing the search will find. I guess it should work since you said your search is working.

Comment: Must head to bed now, but if you can find a way to upload your entire excel file somewhere, I'll look out for it in the morning.

Comment: Oh, just saw you already did. Working on my phone  so missed that. Will return in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on the file you uploaded to Google Drive (as at 2017-06-08, 09:01 UK Time).

I lost a few controls when trying to open the workbook, perhaps our versions of Excel are too different for mine to cope with them. These were your date controls `dtp2` and `dtp3`. I commented out code relating to these whenever they caused me trouble. Hopefully that doesn't negatively affect what follows ...

**Main Suggestions**

- To get things to run at all I had to declare the `lastrow` variable and the `cevap` variable.
- Your `listbox1` is allowing multi-select. If you want to update just one row, you need to ensure that only one row is selected. Within the "Behaviour" section of the control properties, I'd change `MultiSelect` to `0 - fmMultiSelectSingle`.
- Because you were allowing multi-select, `listbox1.value` wasn't working. You have to do it differently when you allow multi-select (see [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/GettheselecteditemsinaListBox.htm)). But assuming you're okay with single-select, you don't need to worry about that.
- When you use your `Find ... Activate` you'll then get a different error. Excel can't `Activate` the spreadsheet because `Userform1` retains focus. You might be able to change that by making the form "non-modal", but I wouldn't. Instead, rather than, for example:

  ```
  Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, _
     LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
  sonsat = ActiveCell.Row
  ```

  I'd do

  ```
  sonsat = Sheets("logbook").Range("A1:A" & 
     lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, _
  LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
  ```

  Which avoid's the need to `Activate`. After that the code should run without complaining.
- However, it still doesn't do what you want. The value of the listbox is based on your bound column, which you've set to the be first column. That value doesn't uniquely identify the row. As a result, when you run the update/delete the code updates/deletes the first matching row.

**Minor Matters**

- There is currently nothing preventing the user selecting and updating/deleting the header row. Personally, I'd take them out of the listbox (start at A2 instead of A1) and add them as "column headings" in the form.
- I'm guessing the title of the form should be "Data Entry Application" not "Data Entery Application".

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your replies and helps. 
sorry about the grammar and mistypes.
I did change the "sonsat", and also I changed the listbox to single-select and everything pretty much working. but another problem came up. I can update up to row 1391. Also when I update an item (for example the first item), when I double click on it the inbound, outbound, 3rd party and International option they don't show the value in the userform.

Comment: I have created this userform and then I copy the data from another excel file into new excel file which has the userform. is this might be a problem?

Comment: Not sure how soon I'll be able to look at this. It would probably be worth you submitting it as a new question. Feel free to tag me (like this: @SteveLovell) in a comment on it and I'll have a look when I can.

Comment: When I click on an item blew row 1391, the Run-time error'91' comes up " Object variable or with block variable not set" and debug
    Sheets("Logbook").Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
 in listbox1_click()

Comment: The issue with the checkboxes and option buttons is that the call values are "X" and "-" but the controls need to be set to "True" and "False". You need to convert the values (both when reading and writing records). The 1391 issue, I cannot replicate with the version I have.

Comment: I have a hunch about the other issue, namely that your new records have not been assigned an ID to uniquely identify them, so 'find' fails.